# Moving to Windows 8 get "InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program"

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, windows-8

I'm developing a `.NET 4.0` application with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper) on Windows 7. Today I get the source code from `SVN` to a new Windows 8 machine, build and then run the app, it throws me:

> InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid
>   program

I rebuild the source codes and it runs well on all other three Windows 7 machines. I guess it does matter with Windows 8. I write the following small console application. I build the source code on Windows 8 and it does run well on Windows 7 but doesn't on Windows 8. So it's something about the runtime on Windows 8. It seems only something wrong with the enum type whose underlying type is not the default type, Int32.

After googling, people say it's about JIT compiler but I still have no idea. I use VS 2010 targeted .NET 4.0 on both Windows 7 and Windows 8. Does any change about this in Windows 8? I'm reading the Source code of AutoMapper. I think it really something wrong with C# or CLI. Hope you give some clue. Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    enum PriorityModel  { High, Normal, Low }
    enum PriorityDto { High, Normal, Low }

    enum PriorityModel2 : byte { High, Normal, Low }
    enum PriorityDto2 : byte { High, Normal, Low }

    enum PriorityModel3 : short { High, Normal, Low }
    enum PriorityDto3 : short { High, Normal, Low }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PriorityModel, PriorityDto>();  // OK
        Mapper.CreateMap<PriorityModel2, PriorityDto2>();  // [InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
        Mapper.CreateMap<PriorityModel3, PriorityDto3>();  // [InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

exception stacktrace:

```
[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method) +0
   System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target) +43
   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate() +81
   System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator) +205
   AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateGet(FieldInfo field) +156
   AutoMapper.Internal.FieldGetter..ctor(FieldInfo fieldInfo) +60
   AutoMapper.ReflectionHelper.ToMemberAccessor(MemberInfo accessorCandidate) +124
   AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory.CreateTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMappingOptions options, MemberList memberList) +269
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateTypeMap(Type source, Type destination, String profileName, MemberList memberList) +86
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap(String profileName, MemberList memberList) +45
   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap() +13
   AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap() +51
```

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. I wonder if this is a 4.5 issue since win8 ships with .NET 4.5 (note 4.5 is an over-the-top install on top of 4.0, so even if targeting 4.0 you can be using 4.5)

Comment: Hi Marc, Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version.ToString()) says 4.0.30319.17929 other than 4.5.

Comment: and what does it show on the other machine? Btw, most sources I've just checked list that version-number as being .net 4.5. The public-friendly version number and the internal geek-friendly version number are not always the same.

Comment: This rings a bell, a bug in a beta version of the .NET 4.5 jitter.  Which you are likely to encounter on a Windows 8 box.  Be sure to obtain (or wait for) the release version of Windows 8.  You can get it now through an MSDN subscription.  The CLR version is still 4.0.30319 btw.

Comment: Hans, I just have the RTM Windows 8 on my machine. That's say, the bug still exists on RTM?